# Loading Several Google Maps on One Page - Slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am creating a page for a non-profit listing their Board of Directors. In a lightbox I have additional information including a Google Map pinpointing their business location. It looks great however they have several board of directors (10+) and that many Google Maps cause the page to load very slowly. I can barely scroll it is loading so slowly. (I am using Firefox 20) When I test in Chrome it isn't as slow but at times can be slow.

Is there a way to only load Google Maps at all until the lightbox is opened?

Note: Once I see Google Maps stop loading the page runs very smooth. It is only slow and jerky while Google Maps is loading.

Here is my Lightbox HTML:

```
<div class="hide">
 <div id="name">
  <div class="grid_8">
   <p class="bio">Info Goes Here</p>
   <p>Info Goes Here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4">
   <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="map-code"></iframe><br /><small><a target="_blank" href="map-link" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Fancybox 2 and jQuery 1.8.3.

How do I stop the maps from loading until the lightbox is triggered?

Comment: instead of initializing the map onLoad initialize it when the Fancybox opens

Comment: @Ares - How do I do that?

Comment: share your code about how you are initializing the map.

Comment: @Ares - I am using Googles iframe of the map. I do nothing to initialize the map.

Comment: @Ares - I ended up going the route you were probably thinking. See my answer below for what I ended up doing to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out a way to do this using the `<iframe>` embed code. What I have done is use [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/en/) to load the maps when Fancybox is called. Here is an example of the code I used:

```
$(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         beforeLoad : function() {  
            $("#map").gmap3({
                 // MAP OPTIONS
            });
         }
   });  
});
```